# Redirecting domain in htaccess works on all subpages but not domain itself

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect every page at shipcompliantblog.com to the new domain, which is shipcompliant.com/blog. I'm using the code below, which is redirecting all blog posts but not the domain shipcompliantblog.com itself:

```
#turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shipcompliantblog\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shipcompliant.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Anyone see something I'm missing?

In case it matters, the host for shipcompliantblog.com is GoDaddy.

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: Hey Amit, that's interesting - do you mean if you go to shipcompliantblog.com, your browser redirects you to shipcompliant.com/blog?

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

1) `RedirectMatch ^/$ /blog/`

2) Depending on your hosting provider, you can setup a redirect to /blog there. Many offer this service. But sounds like option 1 is the best route for you

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't seem to have any effect. I put it at the end of my code, after the RewriteRule. Let me know if it needs to be placed somewhere else.